# Permissions to register a new agent to an agent pool

Tags: azure-devops

I am attempting to register an agent to an agent pool in an on-premises Azure DevOps instance (version 17.143.28621.4) , following the [current documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops).

I didn't create the agent pool, but the server administrator has added me as an administrator of the pool - which according to the documentation is the only permission needed to register an agent.

However, when I attempt to register the agent using the command-line tool, I get the following error:

> Connecting to the server. Access denied. Harper, Ed needs Manage
> permissions for pool  to perform the action. For more
> information, contact the Azure DevOps Server administrator.
>
> Failed to add the agent.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit

The server admin also tried adding me to the `build administrators` group for the project associated with the agent pool. This had no effect and I got the same error.

What permission/role membership do I need to add agents to the pool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly an answer on the permissions needed, but as a member of the project `build administrator` role, I could create a new agent pool.

I was able to add the agent to the new pool without any problems.

Answer (score 7):

I met the exactly same issue here. And the solution for my case is pretty simple - following the steps Microsoft provides exactly, based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops).

In the [permission section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#confirm-the-user-has-permission) of document, it mentions you need to check our permission from **Orgnazation settings**. It seems like the Orignazation level setting and Project level setting for the same agent pool have separate permission groups. So you could try to do the following from Orgnazation settings.

> I didn't create the agent pool, but the server administrator has added me as an administrator of the pool - which according to the documentation is the only permission needed to register an agent.

That's how I solved my problem(intially I only have administrator permission from the Project setting -> agent pool setting and see same error).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. I am using a dedicated service-account as the ADO user and local agent user. I adjusted their permissions as described in this post, adding it as an Administrator to the pool at the Project level, and as a member of the Build Administrators in the Project. I was using a PAT token created under that user's account with the specified permissions (Read+Manage Agent Pools). The PAT was accepted by the command, but I would still get this error:

```
Access denied. my_service_account needs Manage permissions for pool myAgentPool to perform the action. For more information, contact the Azure DevOps Server administrator.
```

My actual ADO account is Project Admin so I just created a new PAT with full access and used that instead and it worked. Since the PAT is only needed at initial registration, I immediately revoked the PAT.
What worked