# Cannot create new agent pool, Access denied error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a new agent pool by:
`Organization Settings>>Agent pools>>new agent pool`.
I'm getting Error message:

[image: Access denied....needs Manage Permission...]

Thing is I'm Admin and I don't know what permission I need to add.
In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56152332/permissions-to-register-a-new-agent-to-an-agent-pool) thread,
It was suggested that I need to be 'build administrator' which I am.

***EDIT***
So regarding both responses:
I am both in project administrator and build administrator groups but I'm not in 'Project Collection Administrators' group.
I will update if it solved the issue after I will be added to this group.

Comment: Hi, how are things going? Can you create the agent pool successfully now?

Comment: Yes! thanks for the help! I edited the question with your solution.

Comment: because I have "less then 15 reputation" it doesn't show I did...

Comment: Do you mean it could not display the content you edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter `Access denied` error or `You do not have permission to manage this pool’s roles` error, these are all because of your role. I assume you are not the member of **Project Collection Administrators**.

Please contact org owner or anyone whose role is PCA, ask for adding your account as PCA member. This is the highest permission role which only after Org owner.

And also, you can let your org owner, PCA member or the one who has the role of agent pool administrator add you as **the administrator of All agent pool**. Since you do not have enough permission now, you must contact them to finish this operation.

Comment: This answer has solved the issue for me. Someone with a enough privilege should enter 'Organization settings', then 'permissions'. Enter 'Project Collection Administrators', go to 'members' tab and click 'add members'.

Answer (score 1):

In the agent pools page, click on "All agent pools" on the top, then in the right side click "Add", then add your user with "Administrator" Role:

[image]

Comment: mmm... I'm getting "You do not have permission to manage this pool’s roles". what permission do I need here?

Comment: Send a screenshot of your permissions (from the organization settings -> Permissions)